# eclipse Milo Certificate Chain on Server

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, opc-ua, milo

I'm trying to set up an example server that will deliver a correct certificate Chain when SignAndEncrypt mode is used.

Using the example provided, the server will only deliver the certificate but not the chain to the root certificate, even though I included the root certificate (no intermediate used) in the .pfx file.

I worked my way to OpcUaServer.java and and included the Certificate Chain, but OpcUaServer.java calls:

```
UaStackServer addEndpoint(String endpointUri,
                          String bindAddress,
                          X509Certificate certificate,
                          SecurityPolicy securityPolicy,
                          MessageSecurityMode messageSecurity);
```

Which is not overloaded to take a certificate chain, so I'm kind of stuck.

How can I set up an (example) OPC UA Milo Server that delivers the full certificate chain instead of only delivering the server certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Starting in release 0.1.4 the client and server can both be configured with certificate chains.

The chain for the client can configured by calling `setCertificateChain()` when building the config object.

The chain for the server can be configured by using the constructor for `DefaultCertificateManager` that accepts a chain or by implementing `getCertificateChain` if you use your own implementation of `CertificateManager`.

The PR that implements this is [here](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/pull/131).

Comment: Thank you. I tried this for the Server but monitoring the connection in wireshark, the root certificate is not transmitted to the client (UaExpert, but that should not matter). I will update if I find out why this is.

Comment: The server does send the configured chain in the asymmetric security header, which is where it matters most, but it's not currently returning the chain in the ServerCertificate field of the EndpointDescriptions it returns. I'll need to look into whether this is correct behavior or not. Does this match what you're seeing?